# How can I solve to my application calls ../destroy?

Tags: http-status-code-404

My application calls destroy but it doesn't found. What does it call this destroy? what is it? thanks.

[chrome console picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enXMn.jpg)

[I get 404 error at index.html first line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B3M9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. destroy is backstretch's destroy. regards